# Find the matching response for the TCP request + tcpdump

Tags: tcpdump

I'm trying my hand with tcpdump..

The eventually tcpdump command looks like this

```
sudo tcpdump -i eth0 -n -tt 'tcp port 6379 or port 5432 and (((ip[2:2] - ((ip[0]&0xf)<<2))  - ((tcp[12]&0xf0)>>2)) != 0)'
```

My understanding is that ..

I'm filtering port `6379` and port `5432` for packets that contains data using `(((ip[2:2] - ((ip[0]&0xf)<<2))  - ((tcp[12]&0xf0)>>2)) != 0)`

When I run this I see the following output.

```
1521257077.232079 IP 10.240.0.40.37978 > 10.240.0.9.6379: Flags [P.], seq 1142349306:1142349326, ack 4173563637, win 222, options [nop,nop,TS val 1441301100 ecr 2758188018], length 20: RESP "del" "a"
1521257077.234193 IP 10.240.0.9.6379 > 10.240.0.40.37978: Flags [P.], seq 1:5, ack 20, win 220, options [nop,nop,TS val 2758213022 ecr 1441301100], length 4: RESP "0"
1521257100.633083 IP 10.240.0.40.37978 > 10.240.0.9.6379: Flags [P.], seq 20:40, ack 5, win 222, options [nop,nop,TS val 1441306950 ecr 2758213022], length 20: RESP "del" "a"
1521257100.634825 IP 10.240.0.9.6379 > 10.240.0.40.37978: Flags [P.], seq 5:9, ack 40, win 220, options [nop,nop,TS val 2758218872 ecr 1441306950], length 4: RESP "0"
```

My goal is to correctly match the TCP request with the appropriate response.

I getting some inference from the seq number and ack like here

```
1521257100.633083 IP 10.240.0.40.37978 > 10.240.0.9.6379: Flags [P.], seq 20:40, ack 5, win 222, options [nop,nop,TS val 1441306950 ecr 2758213022], length 20: RESP "del" "a"

1521257100.634825 IP 10.240.0.9.6379 > 10.240.0.40.37978: Flags [P.], seq 5:9, ack 40, win 220, options [nop,nop,TS val 2758218872 ecr 1441306950], length 4: RESP "0"
```

I see `ack(40)` for a `seq 20:40` but the problem is that I'm not able to draw inference for the 1st packet sent (at the start of the connection)

```
1521257077.232079 IP 10.240.0.40.37978 > 10.240.0.9.6379: Flags [P.], seq 1142349306:1142349326, ack 4173563637, win 222, options [nop,nop,TS val 1441301100 ecr 2758188018], length 20: RESP "del" "a"
1521257077.234193 IP 10.240.0.9.6379 > 10.240.0.40.37978: Flags [P.], seq 1:5, ack 20, win 220, options [nop,nop,TS val 2758213022 ecr 1441301100], length 4: RESP "0"
```

My only guess is the to look at the `TCP val` and `ECR` value.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: seems like you want to capture the response from redis ? not so sure about your question, can you give more explanation

Comment: In short, I want to calculate the time a request took to respond. So match the request with a response and calculate the time difference.

Comment: suggest that you calculate the latency around high level redis api. why can't you link the req and resp by `seq`; even lost the 1st packet, i think it will work well detecting the following packet.

Comment: I do not follow  `even lost the 1st packet,`. Sorry. :(

Comment: sorry about the misunderstanding. so you want to find a solution to identify the first packet sent. use `TS val` and `ECR` is ok.